# Como fazer para organizar cada posição da minha lista em ordem crescente?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Esse é o meu codigo:

```
a = [[3,2,1],[4,3,2],[5,4,3]]

for i in range(0, len(a)):
    for j in range(0, len(a[i])):
        a[i].sort()

 print(a)
```

O problema é que só esta organizando a primeira posição. Alguém poderia me dar uma orientação?

Comment: Obrigado Thiago!

Comment: por que está usando dois for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todas as respostas resolvem o problema, porém a resposta dada pelo @Thiago Magalhães é a que mais se relaciona com a minha duvida.

```
  a = [[3,2,1],[4,3,2],[5,4,3]]

  for i in range(0, len(a)):
       a[i].sort()
  print(a)
```

Answer (score 4):

Simplesmente faça:

```
def ordena_lista(lista):
    for item in lista:
        item.sort()
```

O método `sort()` atua diretamente na lista modificando o objeto sem criá-lo novamente.

```
>>> lista = [[1, 4, 3, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
>>> ordena_lista(lista)
>>> lista
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Como complemento ao que já foi dito, também consegue fazer a ordenação que quer utilizando [*list compreehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) que lhe fica em uma linha:

```
a = [sorted(lista) for lista in a]
print(a) # [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]
```

Neste caso usei o `sorted` em vez de `sort` para devolver a sub-lista ordenada e atribuir ao elemento correto.

Assim como o @AndersonCarlosWoss comentou, o `sorted` devolve uma nova lista ordenada ao invés de modificar a original, em contraste com o `sort` que altera a original. No caso como o resultado foi atribuido de novo sobre `a` ficou na mesma apenas com a nova lista ordenada, mas se tivesse outras variaveis que referissem a lista original essa iria manter-se intacta.

Um exemplo mais claro deste efeito seria:

```
>>> x = [5, 1, 2, 4]
>>> y = sorted(x)
>>> x
[5, 1, 2, 4]
>>> y
[1, 2, 4, 5]
```

[Veja este exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/hZQNYc)

Answer (score 1):

Se você não for utilizar a lista desordenada é bom você utilizar o método `list.sort()` ao invés de `sorted(list)`, pois como já foi dito aqui, a segunda cria uma nova lista, então você vai estar utilizar memória à toa. 
Neste caso também não é bom não utilizar **list compreehension**, pois vai utilizar memória desnecessária da mesma forma, ao mapear a saída nula de `list.sort()` em uma nova lista. Então, a forma mais simples, rápida e econômica de fazer isso é:

```
for lista in listas:
   lista.sort()
```